# Reload youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

I need to load, destroy, and reload the [YouTube Upload Widget](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget), but unfortunately the reloading it does not work.

I performed the following steps:

1. I loaded the Youtube Upload Widget as described in the howto - **works**
2. I capture a video from the webcam - **works**
3. I destroy the widget using `widget.destroy(`) - **works**
4. I remove the script element from the HTML - **works**
5. I reload the API as in step 1 - **nothing happens**

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You need to provide details on what you've tried and what the results were. As it stands, you're saying "things don't work for me, please look into your crystal ball and tell me why".

Comment: I tried steps 1-5 and the result of step 5 is that nothing happens (as described in my post). I expected a reloading of the API and the plugging in of the iframe which does not happen. No error message, simply nothing.

Comment: Which script element are you talking about removing? The one at `http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` that provides the YT.* API? And can you point to a live code sample (jsfiddle.net or otherwise)?

Comment: In step 4, I removed the iframe API and the widget API in order to reload them in step 5. You can find a live code sample at http://jsfiddle.net/kTGW3/. The reloading takes place in the toggleWebcam() function. In the meantime I could get it working by directly putting the IFRAME in the HTML page instead of the DIV placeholder. Is this a good work-around or will it break as soon as the API changes?

Answer (score 5):

`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` only will be called once per page, when the `window.YT.*` interface is loaded via the external script. Removing the `<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api">` element from the page and then re-adding it won't trigger `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` again.

If you want to destroy the `<iframe>` that contains the upload widget and then create a new widget hosted in a new `<div>` then that should work, but you don't have to do it from within the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` callback the second time. `window.YT.UploadWidget()` is already available at that point, so feel free to use that interface directly from anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem and works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are my hero! That's exactly the problem. Takes me hours to figure out what the problem was. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()** is only called once when the YouTube API is loaded. The answer is to  add a another check to YouTube's step 2:

```
if (typeof tag === "undefined") { 
  // if first run load the YT API which will call the correct functions.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
} else {
   // if YT api already loaded, we need to call the function.
   onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
}
```

Good luck.